# Extract one number from another number in PHP

Tags: php

so tonight i was trying to create a function that will check if a credit card is valid or not.
However i'm stuck here.
In my calcul, i get number such as 10, 56, 30... number with 2 numbers.

(I mean, 1 is a number with 1 number just like 2, 3, 4 ,5 6, 7 , 8 ,9.. number with two numbers would be 10 ans higher.)

What I need to do is :

- Get the first number and add it to a new variable, and do the same thing with another variable.

Example:

I have this number -> 23

I need to :

$var1 = 2;

$var2 = 3;

I wanted to use the function subtr, but it looks like it doesn't works with numbers ..

Thanks for reading !!

Comment: i don't understand your approach but the proper way to do it is ^^^^^^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you get something from this. Casting the number into a string first and then split the number using substr() after that cast the splitted value to integer again:

```
$num = 23;
$str_num = (string)$num;

$var1 = (int)substr($str_num, 0, 1);
$var2 = (int)substr($str_num, 1, 1);
```

Or using a pure numbers:

```
$num = 23;

$var2 = $num % 10;
$var1 = ($num - $var2) / 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Credit card numbers can be validated using an algorithm called the [Luhn Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm).

If you need this in a project, don't reinvent the wheel. Check out [this project](https://github.com/inacho/php-credit-card-validator) on github.

Comment: I was trying to make my own class for that using the Luhn Algorithm indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this using purely numbers (without ever casting to strings). This'll also work on any length of numbers assigning it to $var1, $var2, ... , $varn for n length number.

```
$num = 23;
$count = 1;
while ($num > 0) {
    $var = "var".$count++;
    $$var = $num % 10;
    $num = intval($num / 10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a numeric solution

```
$num = 23;
$var1 = floor($num / 10);
$var2 = $num % 10;
echo "$var1 $var2";
```